# Unexpected disk label

Tags: storage

I have a USB with a disk-label and a file-system label.
I am wondering how to change the disk-label.

Everywhere I read that there is no disk-label. And that is what I though, but I seem to have one.

Where is this label stored and how can I change it?

```
#↳ lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label
sda
├─sda1 /                         debian-root
├─sda3 /home                     home
└─sda4 [SWAP]
sdd
└─sdd2 /media/user1/extra        extra
sde                              Debian 8.10.0 amd64 1
└─sde1 /media/user1/label1       label1
```

```
#↳ ll /dev/disk/by-label/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 23 10:32  label1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 16 14:43  debian-root -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 23 10:32 'Debian\x208.10.0\x20amd64\x201' -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 22 11:44  extra -> ../../sdd2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 16 14:43  home -> ../../sda3
```

```
#↳ /sbin/fdisk -l  /dev/sde
Disk /dev/sde: 14.9 GiB, 16025387008 bytes, 31299584 sectors
Disk model: STORE N GO
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4f71a989

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sde1        2048 31299583 31297536 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

```
#↳ strings /dev/sde | head -n 7
EFI PART
Apple
Apple_partition_map
Apple_HFS
CD001
                                Debian 8.10.0 amd64 1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                XORRISO-1.4.6 2016.09.16.133001, LIBISOBURN-1.4.6, LIBISOFS-1.4.6, LIBBURN-1.4.6
```

Update: Do I have more than one partition table? And, what are the rules for how this is handled?

```
#↳ /sbin/wipefs /dev/sde
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE    UUID                   LABEL
sde    0x8001 iso9660 2017-12-09-22-16-00-00 Debian 8.10.0 amd64 1
sde    0x1fe  dos
sde    0x200  gpt
```

---

```
#↳ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess the drive previously had an ISO `dd`-ed on it. The label definitely suggest that and the *EFI* and *Apple* strings found in the superblock also supports that -- ISO files have multiple partition tables on them to allow booting on different systems ([this blogpost](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/11285.html) has a nice detailed explanation for Fedora ISO images, it will be similar for Debian). I would assume that formatting the drive didn't wipe all the remnants of the various metadata correctly and that's why `lsblk` now thinks there is a label on it.

Try running `wipefs /dev/sde` this will show what metadata (lib)blkid sees on the device (I wouldn't be surprised if a broken iso9660 with the label was there) and you can then choose to remove just one of these with `wipefs -o <offset>` to get rid of the label. If you have some data on the partition I suggest making a backup first, just in case the wipe wipefs something it shouldn't. Simply `dd`ing some zeroes to the first few sectors should also do the trick (but that will also destroy the FAT filesystem).

I played a little with the Debian 8 ISO and if I intentionally delete the existing partition table on it without removing the iso9660 I get the same result:

```
$ lsblk /dev/loop0 -o+FSTYPE,LABEL
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS FSTYPE  LABEL
loop0       7:0    0  163M  0 loop             iso9660 Debian 8.10.0 arm64 1
└─loop0p1 259:4    0  162M  0 part             vfat    label1
          label1
```

(I also formatted the partition to VFAT with label *label1* to get the same setup you have)

with `wipefs` reporting both the original iso9660 and the newly created partition table on it:

```
$ sudo wipefs /dev/loop0
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE    UUID                   LABEL
loop0  0x8001 iso9660 2017-12-10-00-50-50-00 Debian 8.10.0 arm64 1
loop0  0x1fe  dos
```

I had to tell fdisk explicitly to not remove the existing formats with `--wipe never`, default behaviour is to remove everything when creating a new partition table, so I don't know what exactly happened in your case, but I think we can safely say the iso9660 format that wasn't removed is to be blamed for the disk label which is actually iso9660 filesystem label.

> Do I have more than one partition table? And, what are the rules for how this is handled?

Yes, you have. The DOS partition table wins because it's first. You can access the GPT with `fdisk --type gpt` that should ignore the DOS partition table and allow you to work with the GPT at the later offset.
But on a normal system you don't want to deal with multiple partition tables and I'd suggest just wiping the drive clean to get rid of all previous metadata.

Comment: I also thought it looked like remnants of an ISO files-system, but that does not explain why the label is reported. It must be possible to set a label.

Comment: I added the output of `wipefs` It looks like we are correct. But Why How multiple partition tables (different standard locations?). And, what are the rules to interpret them?

Comment: Hybrid ISO images are a huge mess (but it works!), you can check this old (but still valid) [blogpost](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/11285.html) about Fedora ISO images and the various formats and partition tables on it. The partition tables are at different offsets and the different systems just need to find "their" partition table to use when booting.

Comment: Thanks. Now that all makes sense. I have started the copy of the new(ish) Debian installer, to it. It will wipe it all away. Nothing but this post as a reminder.